# How to change the Web Performance test execution path

Tags: visual-studio-2015, performance-testing, configuration-files, load-testing

I have created a Web Performance and Load Test Project in MS Visual Studio 2015. Under the project, I created some web performance tests.

But we have different team environments and we want to run these tests on all servers, so I changed the url address by using "Context Parameters" under each web performance test

After using the context param, the URL becomes:
`https://{{WebServer}}/WebSite/account/signin` and it works as expected.

But, I want to know is there a **config file** in which I can update server path, so the web test need not be changed every time.
I tried different options in `Local.testsettings` and `test.runsettings`. But could not make it dynamic.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of options.

1. Context parameters may be set in the Load Test. Values set there override values set in a Web Test. Using this method perhaps you could make several copies of the Load Test, one for each of the required environments.
2. Environment variables can set or override the value of a context parameter. Setting an environment variable with the name "Test.MyWebServer" will override the value of the `MyWebServer` context parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for response. But we do not want to repeat the test cases.
At present, we are reading config file in WebTestPlugin class as

```
public class LoginAssistPlugin : WebTestPlugin
{
       ExeConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
       fileMap.ExeConfigFilename = configFilePath;
       _config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
}
```

The above method is written in constructor of the plugin class.
And the server hostname is set as static variable. Then we use other overridable methods from WebTestPlugin class like below to replace the WebContext Parameters in a web performance tests.

```
public override void PreRequest(object sender, PreRequestEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Request.Url = e.Request.Url.Replace("{{WebServer}}", _webServer);
            e.Request.Url = e.Request.Url.Replace("{{IdentityServer}}", _identityServer);

            e.Request.QueryStringParameters.ToList().ForEach(param => param.Value = param.Value.Replace("{{WebServer}}", _webServer));
            e.Request.QueryStringParameters.ToList().ForEach(param => param.Value = param.Value.Replace("{{ClientId}}", _clientId));
            e.Request.QueryStringParameters.ToList().ForEach(param => param.Value = param.Value.Replace("{{WebClientPath}}", _webClientPath));

            //if(e.WebTest.Name == "signin")
            //    e.Request.QueryStringParameters.ToList().ForEach(param => param.Value = param.Value.Replace("{{UserName}}", userName));

            e.Request.Headers.ToList().ForEach(header => header.Value = header.Value.Replace("{{WebClientPath}}", _webClientPath));
            e.Request.Headers.ToList().ForEach(header => header.Value = header.Value.Replace("{{IdentityServer}}", _identityServer));
            e.Request.Headers.ToList().ForEach(header => header.Value = header.Value.Replace("{{WebServer}}", _webServer));
            e.Request.Headers.ToList().ForEach(header => header.Value = header.Value.Replace("{{ClientId}}", _clientId));

            if (_token != null)
            {
                e.Request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + _token);
            }
        }
```

Then this plugin is used in each of web performance tests.
Any more help / tips will be hlpfull.

Comment: This is not an answer. Please edit the original question to include this information. But also please clarify the apparent contradiction between *"so the web test need not be changed every time"* in the question and *"we do not want to repeat the test cases"* above.

Comment: I agree, this is not exact answer, but its satisfying my needs. "We do not want to repeat the test cases means" - We have branches for individual teams and staging and integration environments, we want to run these test on all these environments through command prompts with minimal user interaction. So we needed to read web server paths from config files.  "so the web test need not be changed every time" - also refers to same thing, result on different branches should be visible in MTM. I hope, I have clarified the doubts.